# How to execute a package SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, dts, ssis

Does anyone know how to trigger the execution of a SSIS 2008 package while running a DTS 2000 package?
Actually, my DTS 2000 has to be runned as it is and cannot be converted into a SSIS 2008.
SO is it possible to execute maybe a shell command (Dtutil , etc..) to run this SSIS 2008 package?

Thanks for feedbacks

Comment: yes it shall be triggered within DTS ... any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of doing this.

1. Make the DTS execution a step in a SQL Agent job, and start that job by running the stored procedure `sp_start_job`
2. Run by executing `xp_cmdshell`:

   `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "C:\Package.dtsx"'`

Option two involves configuring xp_cmdshell to run. xp_cmdshell  allows you to issue operating system commands directly to the Windows command shell via T-SQL code - something I'm not entirely comfortable with, so I would go for option 1.

Some helpful links:

- [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx)
- [Execute SSIS Package using the Stored Procedure in T-SQL.](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/Anil/ssas/1487/execute-ssis-package-using-the-stored-procedure-in-t-sql)
- [Executing all SSIS packages in a folder: three methods](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=270)